# How to place text and image next to each other?

Tags: html, css

How can I do something like this?

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="content">
   <img src="somesrc">
   <h3><strong>TITLE</strong></h3>
   <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

I would like to have some space between the title and image.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use css Flex. Add `display: flex` on `.content`.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.content img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.content h3,
.content p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="somesrc">
  <div class="text">
    <h3><strong>TITLE</strong></h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Stew content after `<img>` should be wrapped in a  single `div` to make this work.

Comment: One last question, why did you use .content h3,
.content p {margin: 0;}?

Comment: @Stew Because browser apply some default `margin` on all headings `<h1>-<h6>` and `p` elements. You can ignore them or change as per your needs.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.content,
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  <h3><strong>TITLE</strong></h3>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```